# SFTP of a CSV file using JSch to Mainframes turns the file in to a single line one MF end

Tags: csv, sftp, jsch

I am doing a CSV file SFTP using JSch to a mainframe. The file has multiple rows. However, after the transfer of the file, on the Mainframe it contains all the rows in a single line. Sample code snippet below:

```java
File f1 = new File(FILETOTRANSFER1);
channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f1), f1.getName());
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSch library always uses "binary" mode transfer only. It never converts the file in any way.

So either:

- The file gets (wrongly) converted by the SFTP server on the mainfraime.
- Or (more likely) the file actually is not converted to the format the mainframe requires. Either you need to do the conversion yourself before the upload or convert the file on the server after the upload.